# an issue with updating database table

Tags: php, android, mysql, database

i'm building an app which uses MySQL Database .. i'm trying to send a gps coordinates and also strings and an integer .. the coordinates sending is working fine .. the problem is with the strings and the integer

this is my php script :

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("*****", "*****", "******", "*******");

$lat = $_POST["lat"];
$long = $_POST["long"];
 $id= $_POST["id"];
$pickup= $_POST["pickup"];
$destination = $_POST["destination"];
 $seats= $_POST["seats"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con,"Update user SET  lat=$lat,long=$long , pickup=$pickup,destination=$destination,seats=$seats  WHERE user_id=$id" );

mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;  

echo json_encode($response);?>
```

this is my  table structure :

[database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06Smp.png)

and i don't think that the problem is with the aplication because there is no diffrent between code that i'm using for sending the doubles (lat,long) and strings (pickup , destination).. anyway this is some of my application code :

```
public void send_gps(String pickup,String destination,int seats,int id, double lat,double long) {


    // Response received from the server
    Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);
                builder2.setMessage("error")
                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                        .create()
                        .show();
            }
        }
    };

    gps_request request = new gps_request(pickup,destination,Integer.toString(seats),Integer.toString(id),Double.toString(lat),Double.toString(long), responseListener);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    queue.add(request);

}
```

and this is the class that extends string request

```
public class gps_request extends StringRequest {
private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL = "**********************";
private Map<String, String> params;

public gps_request(String pickup,String destination,String seats,String id,String lat, String long, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
    super(Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();

   params.put("lat", lat);
   params.put("long", long);
    params.put("id", id );
   params.put("pickup", pickup);
    params.put("destination", destination);
    params.put("seats", seats );

}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}}
```

Comment: Problem is that you don't know how to use quotes in query.

Comment: You're using prepared statements, good. But why are you passing parameters as it? Make use of [`mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) function to bind your parameters.

Comment: that's 2nd level `sql injection`

Comment: show the output of `show create table user` via an [edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your query to something like this - note: I guessed at your variable types "i" and "s".

```
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con,"UPDATE user SET lat=?, long=?, pickup=?, destination=?, seats=? WHERE user_id=?");

$statement->bind_param("iisssi", $lat, $long, $pickup, $destination, $seats, $id);

mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
```